# Método Focus() asp net

Tags: asp.net

Tenho uma página com vários controles, quando eu disparo um evento de um botão quero que o foco vá a um textBox que fica lá em baixo da página, porém isto não está ocorrendo simplesmente colocando o método `focus()` no `textBox`. Será que algum outro controle como um `listBox` está interferindo? Porque neste evento que tento colocar o foco num `textBox` também estou passando um índice a fim de que fique selecionado um item da `listBox`: `listBox.SelectedIndex = 0`. Poderia ser também um problema de escopo? Por exemplo, esse `textBox` que deve receber o foco fica em outro `panel`. Eu quero que esse `textBox` receba o foco e que a página desça (a barra horizontal) até ele, entende?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz em JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("textBox").focus();
```

Aí deu certo.